# A limit involving floor functions

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Looking for help on calculating the following limit :
$$\lim_{a\to \infty}\,\frac{\lfloor{\frac{{1+\sqrt{a}}}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{a}{2}}\rfloor}{a},$$
if it exists. It appears to approach $\frac{1}{2}$, but I am unsure how to show this.

Comment: There is no $n$ in your expression.

Comment: It was supposed to read $a$, sorry.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to approach the integer part function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $f(a)$ your sum. Then
$$
\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{a}}{2}+\frac{a}{2}-2}{a} \le f(a) \le \frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{a}}{2}+\frac{a}{2}}{a}.
$$
Since lhs and rhs converge both to $1/2$, then $f(a)\to 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks. In general when dealing with floor function limits, is the strategy to find bounds and isolate the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @WilliamManley Usually yes, however sequences like $(n-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$ are clearly not convergent (even if removing the floor part it would be constantly zero).

Comment: Can you quickly explain how you got these bounds?

Comment: Simply $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor \le x$.

Comment: Yes I think I see now, you edited it right?

Comment: Yes right $\text{ }$